# if (itr != container.end() ) fail to catcht end element

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I have an Iterator class and I want to achive a control in that class without having container information (this is strange I know but I am doing it as homework). So I found a trick that to keep container as a member variable.

Here is my header template Iterator class

```
template <class E, class C= vector<E> >
  class Iterator {
  public:
    Iterator(C c);
    Iterator();
    bool hasNext()noexcept;
    typename C::iterator& next()noexcept;
    void remove()noexcept;
    E& operator *()throw(domain_error);
  private:
    typename C::iterator itr;
    C container;
  };
```

and here my Iterator constructor that initializes member variables.

```
  template<class E, class C>
  Iterator<E, C>::Iterator(C c) {
    container =c;
    itr= c.begin();
  }
```

and here is my problem function `Iterator<E,C>::hasNext`

```
  template<class E, class C>
  bool
  Iterator<E,C>::hasNext()noexcept {
     return (itr != container.end()); //can not catch end element
  }
```

Because of `Iterator::hasNext` function fails to catch end point an infinite loop occur in `hashSet::addAll` function. (this is another class that used Iterator class as helper class)

```
  template<class E, class C>
  void
  HashSet<E, C>::addAll(C &c)noexcept {
    Iterator<E,C> itr = Iterator<E,C>(c);
    while(itr.hasNext()){
      add(*itr);
      itr.next();
    }
  }
```

> hashSet::add(E e) function
>
> ```
>  template<class E, class C>
>   void
>   HashSet<E, C>::add(E e)noexcept {
>     if(contains(e)!=true){
>       // cerr<<"hashSet::add "<< e <<endl;
>       container.insert(container.end(),e);
>     }
>   }
> ```

Comment: What is `add()`? Does it do something to invalidate the iterator you're trying to use? (This looks like you're trying to write Java code in c++... that's rarely a good idea.)

Comment: And what's the definition of end? Of the != operator? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Shawn, The definition of homework is to develop a library that is similar to Java structured collection library as using STL in the back. Also I added add() function to the end and I tried to be more clear about "end"

Comment: You’re initializing itr to the beginning of the container passed in (c) the constructor, but checking the end iterator of the copied container that’s a member variable. That’s a no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template<class E, class C> Iterator<E, C>::Iterator(C c)` and attribute 
`C container;` : you work on a copy of C

so you have to change them to `template<class E, class C> Iterator<E, C>::Iterator(C & c)` with attribute `C & container;`

I you come from Java you have to take care, in Java an object is given by address, in C++ without the modifier '&' an object is given by value (copied)

Comment: declaring `C& container` (and inititializing with `Iterator(C c) : container(c)`) could help

Comment: thank you guys, to indicate that point, I hold a pointer that point to the initial container and it is solved.                (C * container; )

Comment: @AdrianW -- that should be `Iterator(C& c)`.

Comment: AdrianW, you are right, I also changed constructor with this : Iterator(C& c); @bruno, thanks again to remember the idea but if you change your answe according to AdrianW's comment and my comment it would be helpful to the others.

Comment: @hsn I added new signatures explicitly, but for me that was implicit in my previous version